# Median of Sorted arrays of different lengths

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting, median

I have following algorithm to calculate median of two sorted arrays of the same length.

If we have arrays of different sizes, is it still true that the actual median will always lie between the median of arrays and then between medians of subarrays that will be selected as we proceed?

**Algorithm:**

1. Calculate the medians m1 and m2 of the input arrays ar1[] 
      and ar2[] respectively.
2. If m1 and m2 both are equal then we are done.
        return m1 (or m2)
3. If m1 is greater than m2, then median is present in one 
      of the below two subarrays.

   1. From first element of ar1 to m1 (`ar1[0...|_n/2_|]`)
   2. From m2 to last element of ar2  (`ar2[|_n/2_|...n-1]`)
4. If m2 is greater than m1, then median is present in one
      of the below two subarrays.

   1. From m1 to last element of ar1  (`ar1[|_n/2_|...n-1]`)
   2. From first element of ar2 to m2 (`ar2[0...|_n/2_|]`)
5. Repeat the above process until size of both the subarrays 
      becomes 2.
6. If size of the two arrays is 2 then use below formula to get 
     the median.

   ```
   Median = (max(ar1[0], ar2[0]) + min(ar1[1], ar2[1]))/2
   ```

**Example:**

```
ar1[] = {1, 12, 15, 26, 38}
ar2[] = {2, 13, 17, 30, 45}
```

For above two arrays m1 = 15 and m2 = 17

For the above ar1[] and ar2[], m1 is smaller than m2. So median is present 
    in one of the following two subarrays.

```
[15, 26, 38] and [2, 13, 17]
```

Let us repeat the process for above two subarrays:

```
m1 = 26 m2 = 13.
```

m1 is greater than m2. So the subarrays become

```
[15, 26] and [13, 17]
```

Now size is 2, so:

```
median = (max(ar1[0], ar2[0]) + min(ar1[1], ar2[1]))/2
       = (max(15, 13) + min(26, 17))/2 
       = (15 + 17)/2
       = 16
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read this [how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and follow the guidelines there to format and refine your question.

Comment: I think the answer is no. What the algorithm does is removing the same amount of elements below and above the median, but from different arrays. So if their length is different you will remove too many or few elements on either side of the median.

Comment: thanx maraca for clearing my confusion

Answer (score 0):

```
double findMedianSortedArrays(int[] A, int[] B) {        
int m = A.length;
int n = B.length;

if (m > n) {
    return findMedianSortedArrays(B, A);
}

int lo = 0;
int hi = m;
while (lo <= hi) {
    int i = (lo + hi) / 2;
    int j = (m + n + 1) / 2 - i;
    int maxLeftA = i == 0 ? Integer.MIN_VALUE : A[i - 1];
    int minRightA = i == m ? Integer.MAX_VALUE : A[i];
    int maxLeftB = j == 0 ? Integer.MIN_VALUE : B[j - 1];
    int minRightB = j == n ? Integer.MAX_VALUE : B[j];
    if (maxLeftA <= minRightB && maxLeftB <= minRightA) {
        if ((m + n) % 2 == 0) {
            return (Math.max(maxLeftA, maxLeftB) + Math.min(minRightA, minRightB)) / 2.0;
        } else {
            return Math.max(maxLeftA, maxLeftB);
        }
    }
    else if (maxLeftA > minRightB) {
        hi = i - 1;
    }
    else {
        lo = i + 1;
    }
}

return 0.0;
```

}